# Follow calls across server/service boundaries with New Relic

Tags: monitoring, newrelic

For simplicity sake, imagine the following setup:

`[browser] --http--> [c# mvc] --http--> [c# rest api] --http--> [Solr]`

Each node has a New Relic agent installed. How can one track a request across this topology? Currently we can view data per node but correlating this to another node is not possible.

I saw some examples of explicitly adding headers to code that initiate the http request, but surely this could be achieved without 'polluting' code with non business related statements. 
I've worked with Dynatrace and they provide this (for a java environment) quite transparently. I would imagine New relic would be able to do the same. But I need help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for New Relic's [Cross Application Traces](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/cross-application-traces/introduction-cross-application-traces). The New Relic support site includes information on [troubleshooting cross application traces](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/cross-application-traces/troubleshoot-cross-application-tracing).

If your apps are all running the latest version of the New Relic agent and if they are communicating with each other via one of the supported protocols then you should see these traces automatically. Additionally, you can view the relationships between your services using the [New Relic Service Maps](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/data-analysis/service-maps/get-started/introduction-service-maps).

Comment: I guess we cannot track this (yet) because we have an old license and this feature requires a pro plan.